# efficient way of reading attributes of a file in python

Tags: python, file, class

I have a class whereby I am reading a file which has attributes such as width and height in the format

```
width 50
height 60
```

i want to read the file such that I create instances as I read the file e.g self.width = 50 and self.height = 60 however, I can't find an efficient way to do this, any solutions?

this is my current code at the moment

```
f = open(filename, "r")
width = f.readline().split()
self.width = width[1]
```

Comment: Is there one instance per file? Multiple instances? How do you separate?

Comment: Is there an inefficient way you are doing it now? You've got a file with a couple of lines. You read them line by line, split to find the property name and values. It seems fairly straight forward. Post code youi've got and we can work with it.

Comment: i want to create multiple instances from one file

Comment: @tdelaney i've just put up my code in the post

Comment: In the example, `width` is a list (the result of the split) and you can't assign `self.width` to it. `list` is implemented in C as dos not allow arbitrary attribute assignment. Do you have a class that has a `width` attribute?

Comment: There is nothing special about the name `self` in Python; it's just the conventional name of the first parameter of an instance method. In your example, `self` hasn't been defined, so you can't assign to its `width` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can have it all on 1 line, or instances on each, i.e.
# width 50
# height 60
# or
# # This is the one this solution handles
# width 50 height 60
# width 20 height 10

results = []

f = open(filename, "r")
lineString = f.readline()

while lineString != None:
    line = lineString.split()
    values = {}
    for i in range(0, len(line), 2):
        values[line[i]] = int(line[i + 1]) # Integer, primarily for your case
    results.append(values)
    lineString = f.readline()

print(values)
```

What this is doing is reading each of the values in a line, the first is the name and the second is the value (third, fourth, etc.).

You can alter the code so it merges all the lines together using `results[i].update(results[i+1])` iteratively.